# Android application crash on notification

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to learn to create notifications in Android using this tutorial:

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/

The application will compile and run on my phone, but it crashes when I press the button to show the notification.

I found this error in the log:

> Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder', referenced from method com.androidbegin.notificationtutorial.MainActivity.notification

The solution that I found was to make sure the correct entries are checked on the Order and Export tab in the project properties, then clean the project. I had tried checking the items in various combinations, but nothing worked. I believe when I first created the project, **Android Private Libraries** and **Android Dependencies** were checked (**android-support-v4.jar** was listed, but not checked).

Is there something else I may be missing?

**Edit:** This is the logcat from this application:

```
07-29 12:30:45.776: E/dalvikvm(24133): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder', referenced from method com.androidbegin.notificationtutorial.MainActivity.notification
07-29 12:30:45.776: W/dalvikvm(24133): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 7 (Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;) in Lcom/androidbegin/notificationtutorial/MainActivity;
07-29 12:30:46.026: I/Adreno-EGL(24133): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.045_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1__release_AU ()
07-29 12:30:46.026: I/Adreno-EGL(24133): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
07-29 12:30:46.026: I/Adreno-EGL(24133): Build Date: 03/13/14 Thu
07-29 12:30:46.026: I/Adreno-EGL(24133): Local Branch: 
07-29 12:30:46.026: I/Adreno-EGL(24133): Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.31
07-29 12:30:46.026: I/Adreno-EGL(24133): Local Patches: NONE
07-29 12:30:46.026: I/Adreno-EGL(24133): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.045 +  NOTHING
07-29 12:30:51.692: W/dalvikvm(24133): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4161de18)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133): Process: com.androidbegin.notificationtutorial, PID: 24133
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at com.androidbegin.notificationtutorial.MainActivity.notification(MainActivity.java:60)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at com.androidbegin.notificationtutorial.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18673)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
07-29 12:30:51.702: E/AndroidRuntime(24133):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please post your Logcat ?

Comment: check the support library also, and try

Comment: You should add `android-support-v4.jar` to you build path and build into your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now!

I tried checking **android-support-v4.jar** in the Order and Export tab and cleaned the project, and now my applications can show notifications.

I'm pretty sure I tried this before posting this question, but it didn't work then.